# Why isn't this simple MySQL statement working?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to match a user inputted search term against two tables: posts and galleries. The problem is the union all clause isn't working. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
$query = mysql_query("

    SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
        OR author LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
        OR location LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
        OR excerpt LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
        OR content LIKE '%$searchTerm%'

        UNION ALL

    SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE title LIKE '%$searchTerm%'

        ");
```

Comment: What isn't working?
Do the tables have the same columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `UNION ALL` on two queries, it requires that you're getting back the same number of columns from both tables, with the same data types, in the same order. Since you're doing `SELECT *`, this would imply that both `posts` and `galleries` have exactly the same number of columns, of the same types, in the same order. I doubt this is the case (but I guess you could get lucky).

---

*Editing to add an example of how you could make this work*

You'd need to make the column numbers/types match, which you could do with this sort of method (I'm guessing which columns you need, and just adding "N/A" for columns that I'm assuming don't exist in `galleries`):

```
SELECT title, author, location, excerpt, content
FROM posts
WHERE title LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
    OR author LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
    OR location LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
    OR excerpt LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
    OR content LIKE '%$searchTerm%'

UNION ALL

SELECT title, 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'
FROM galleries
WHERE title LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
```

Comment: Ahh I see, Yes the tables have different named columns and different numbers of columns. So since UNION ALL isn't what I need, what can I use to search both tables, 5 columns from the posts table and 1 from the galleries table?

Comment: @Chad:  that depends on the version of mysql; newer versions do a kind of supersetting of the number and types of columns.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html

Comment: @Clark You can still do it with `UNION ALL`, you'll just have to define the columns explicitly. I don't know much about your table structures, but I'll edit my answer with an example of how it could work.